# How to fix leverage browser cache in mvc 5

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, css

I searched a lot on google . The results i found were all related to .htaaccess file . it said you have to edit this file  with the following changes viz.

I did all the following steps mentioned in the link below but none of them found to be a helpful

http://www.narga.net/speeding-up-wordpress-with-leverage-browser-caching/

Comment: Tell us more. What do you want to do? What is your problem, precisely?

Comment: How to use E tag in Html for fixing Leverage browser cache                                                                                                             https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=flipkart.com    u can check in this link